# How do I substitute dynamic variable value to self

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below code as an example

```
class car(): 

    # init method or constructor 
    def __init__(self, model, color): 
        self.model = model 
        self.color = color 
        self.blue = '#0000FF'
    def show(self): 
        print("Model is", self.model ) 
        print("color is", f'{self.{self.color}}') # self.blue from color var

audi = car("audi a4", "blue") 

audi.show()     # same output as car.show(audi)
```

my expected output is

```
Model is audi a4
color is #0000FF
```

how do I pass a dynamic variable to self?

Comment: Why not just use a dictionary?

Comment: I can use a dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by using a dictionary, for ex:

```
self.colors = {'blue': '#0000FF', 'red': '#FF0000'}
```

and access the corresponding value for a color as `self.colors[self.color]` in your code as:

```
class car():      
    # init method or constructor 
    def __init__(self, model, color): 
        self.model = model 
        self.color = color
        self.colors = {'blue': '#0000FF', 'red': '#FF0000'}
    def show(self): 
        print("Model is", self.model ) 
        print("color is", self.colors[self.color]) 

audi = car("audi a4", "blue") 

audi.show()     # same output as car.show(audi)
```